# How to print content of "generator object Estimator.predict"

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, predict

I have a variable which is `<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x7fc2de02ef20>`. It's the result of `my_predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=functools.partial(ds.eval_input_fn, params))`.

The estimator *should* work properly, since printing its evaluation after the training gives this result: `Evaluations: {'loss': 0.031095365, 'global_step': 25666}`

I want to see it's content, or something at least. It should yield (quoting the tensorflow documents) the "Evaluated values of predictions tensors." I tried:

- print(*my_predictions, sep='\n')
- list(my_predictions)
- next(my_predictions)
- for x in my_predictions: print(x)

The error is always:

```
      The error is: `  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 647, in predict
    for i in range(self._extract_batch_length(preds_evaluated)):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
```

The attributes of `my_predictions` are:

```py
__class__ <class 'generator'>
__del__ <method-wrapper '__del__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__delattr__ <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__dir__ <built-in method __dir__ of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__doc__ None
__eq__ <method-wrapper '__eq__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__format__ <built-in method __format__ of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__ge__ <method-wrapper '__ge__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__getattribute__ <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__gt__ <method-wrapper '__gt__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__hash__ <method-wrapper '__hash__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__init__ <method-wrapper '__init__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__init_subclass__ <built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x8fc1c0>
__iter__ <method-wrapper '__iter__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__le__ <method-wrapper '__le__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__lt__ <method-wrapper '__lt__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__name__ predict
__ne__ <method-wrapper '__ne__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__new__ <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x9075a0>
__next__ <method-wrapper '__next__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__qualname__ Estimator.predict
__reduce__ <built-in method __reduce__ of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__reduce_ex__ <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__repr__ <method-wrapper '__repr__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__setattr__ <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__sizeof__ <built-in method __sizeof__ of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__str__ <method-wrapper '__str__' of generator object at 0x7fc2de02ef20>
__subclasshook__ <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x8fc1c0>
```

What should I do? Am I doing something wrong? It could be a wrong `input_fn` (I was using the same of the evaluation), so now I'll check that.

Comment: What code produced that error message?

Comment: A link to your GitHub repository is not a [mcve].

Comment: I'd have to include too much code, It'd be over 400 lines. Should I do it? Anyway, by changing a bit of code it happened that doing `print(next(my_prediction))` disabled eager execution. Do you know why this could happen?